# Expression invalid

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory error:

```
The expression 'item().$v.collection.$v' cannot be evaluated because property '$v' doesn't exist, available properties are '$t, $v._id.$t, $v._id.$v, $v.id.$t, $v.id.$v, $v.database.$t, $v.database.$v, $v.collection.$t, $v.collection.$v, id, _self, _etag, _rid, _attachments, _ts'
```

How can I get around that ?
I am using this expression in forEach which is connected to lookup activity which is reading values from CosmosDB.  I am interested only in single column, but SQL:

```
select collection from backups
```

didn't work, hence I switched from "Query" to "Table", hence output of lookup activity contains json object with fields containing $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error results from for each activity treats "." as the property accessor, please use the expression "@item()['$v.collection.$v']" to get around the error. Thanks.